# Total number of assertions in a folder run by newman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, newman

I am using newman to run my postman collections. Since there are multiple collections I run the whole folder using newman. The problem I have is that newman displays the assertion count separately for each collection so I have to add them up manually to get the total number of assertions.

Is there anyway that I can get the total count of assertions for the entire folder ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're understanding of running a collection is please? Newman can only run 1 collection at a time. Do you have 1 collection and multiple folders with it?

Comment: I have all my postman collections in one folder. And I use newman to run the entire folder at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to npm script that runs all collections inside a folder then something like this would work. It is a very primitive solution but I think that there is no other way because we call `newman.run` multiple times.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var newman = require('newman'),
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir('./collections', function (err, files) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    files = files.filter(function (file) {
        return (/^((?!(package(-lock)?))|.+)\.json/).test(file);
    });
    
    console.log(files);

    var failedTests = 0;
    var completed = 0;
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        newman.run({
            collection: require(`./collections/${file}`),
            reporters: 'cli',
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
        }).on('done', function (err, summary) {
            var collectionName = summary.collection.name;
            summary.run.failures.forEach(failure=>{
                failedTests++;
            });
            completed++;
            if(completed == files.length){
                if(failedTests != 0){
                    console.log("Run completed!");
                    console.log("Tests failed: "+ numFailedTests);
                }else{
                    console.log("No failed tests");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Less precise but works for us - grepping for the assertions, e.g.

```
grep -r "pm.test" /src/newman-tests/* | wc -l
```